# How to retrieve the matched word Text Search

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to retrieve the word text search rows. For example, if I search input as 'water Bottel', I need an output like 'Water Soap Bottel','Water Milk Bottel','Water Copper Bottel'. I know how to use LIKE Operator.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SearchText') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #SearchText



CREATE TABLE #SearchText
(
    ProductId INT,
    ProductName VARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO #SearchText VALUES

    (1,'Water Soap Bottel'),
    (2,'Water Milk Bottel'),
    (3,'Wooden Box'),
    (4,'Water Plastic Bottel'),
    (5,'Water Copper Bottel')
```

Comment: Do you also need to return `bottel water`?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I need word match

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm VARCHAR(100) = 'water bottel'

SELECT *
FROM #SearchText
WHERE ProductName LIKE '%' + REPLACE(@SearchTerm, ' ', '%') + '%'
```

However if you need to also return a row containing the phrase `bottel water`, the order of those words will mean the above doesn't work. In that case you will need to break up the query into multiple words, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM #SearchText
WHERE ProductName LIKE '%water%'
AND ProductName LIKE '%bottel%'
```

If you have a [full text index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017) on that table, you could use [`CONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT *
FROM #SearchText
WHERE CONTAINS(ProductName, '"water" AND "bottel"')
```

Comment: G, As per my input 'Water Bottle' it's working, but For example, if I enter 'Water Bottle Cap'.I need the same records also as 'Water Soap Bottel','Water Milk Bottel','Water Copper Bottel' because word match exists. what I expect is I need word match as well as total my input if exists otherwise, word match.

Comment: So you mean something like `WHERE ProductName  = 'water bottel' OR (...the stuff shown above...)`?

Comment: Yes David, total input match as well as word match, for example, if enter one row as  ''Water Bottel Cap". I need this one and remaining rows word matched either Water or Bottle etc...

Comment: So that is your answer then.

Answer (score 1):

You can split data on space and search if the splitted word match the splitted productname :

If all searched word must matches :

```
SELECT *
FROM   #SearchText st
WHERE  ( SELECT COUNT(value)
         FROM   STRING_SPLIT('water Bottel', ' ') ) = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                                                        FROM   STRING_SPLIT(st.ProductName, ' ') AS sv
                                                        JOIN   STRING_SPLIT('water Bottel', ' ') AS ss
                                                          ON sv.value = ss.value )
```

If one or more word must match:

```
SELECT *
FROM   #SearchText st
WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                FROM   STRING_SPLIT(st.ProductName, ' ') AS sv
                JOIN   STRING_SPLIT('water Bottel', ' ') AS ss
                  ON sv.value = ss.value )
```

Note : The `string_split` function is built-in on SQL Server 2016, you can search a create a custom implementation if you use a lower version.

Comment: May be worth noting this will only work with SQL Server 2016 and later (with an appropriate compat level of course)

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE` operator.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM #SearchText
WHERE LOWER(ProductName) LIKE '%water%'
        AND LOWER(ProductName) LIKE '%bottel%'
```

You can ommit `LOWER(...)` function if collaction of column/database/server is case insensitive.